# What are some ways to wire rear speakers in a home theater system?

Tags: wiring, home-theater, audio, speakers

I have two rear speakers, that I never use, since I don't have a good way (yet) to wire them.
I have a hardwood floor. And the side of the room that is nearest to the TV+Audio source is open. So I don't have a wall to run the cable next to it.

Comment: I think the last sentence pushes this question off topic.  I would be a good question if it were about techniques for fishing wire, but then it would not matter that it's a home theatre system, it would be the same for any kind of wire.

Comment: How about through basement/crawl space, attic, behind baseboards? Or are all of these out of the question?

Comment: I suggest you remove the last sentence and the question will be perfectly on-topic. I would do it but I don't have edit rights *sob*

Comment: maybe think about wirelss?

Comment: @Mohlsen, I don't know if humour was intended there or not... these things can get lost on the internet...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're installing in room where you can't drop above or below the room to run your cables, consider putting up crown molding -- it typically leaves a small channel behind it which is ideal for hiding speaker cables.

You can then punch holes in the top of the wall where you need to run vertically, fish the wires through, staple it up into the corner, then install the crown molding to hide everything.

You can also go the low route, and hide them behind your baseboards, but there isn't always a void behind them, so this could get a little messier if you have to trim away drywall (or plaster in older homes) to create a channel you can use.  You also have problems with baseboards if you have to go past any doorways.

Comment: It might be better (and easier) to just trim a channel in the baseboard. Depending on the gauge of wire, this could 'easily' be done with a circular saw, though a router or table saw would probably work better. Depending on the base board, of course.

Comment: If there is a door in the doorway (or trim around it) then it's pretty easy to go behind that. The tricky bit would be a doorway that's just drywall with no trim.

Comment: I've done it this way, and definitely recommend it against any attempts to fish the cables through the walls or ceiling.

Comment: @Rob -- you may still have to use the walls, but the advantage is that you're always going vertical through the walls, not through joists; if you have to run in the walls for ceiling mounting (projector, speakers, etc.), you can come in from the wall so you're going with the rafters, rather than having to punch holes through them.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, too. I do drop into the walls to get the cable down to my plug-panel. I just didn't have to fight with joists.

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about using in-ceiling speakers?  Then you could fish the wires through the ceiling (assuming the joists run the right way or you have access to the attic).

Comment: These are great. I got a pair of 3-way 12" cieling-mounted speakers for $AUD160 because I was in thge same boat as the op. Never regretted it.

Comment: @Farseeker - agreed, I used them for my front and rear speakers (8" front in ceiling, 6" rear in the wall) mostly for the better wife-acceptance factor.  Have been very happy with them.

Comment: Haha yes anything that scores on the Wife Acceptance Factor has to be a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Easy setup + affordable wireless solution are now available. 
There are a few soundbar systems with a set of wireless subwoofer and rear satellite speakers

For [example](http://store.vizio.com/home-theater/s4251wb4.html) the Vizio S4251W-B4

Comment: Link only answers are not so good, especially when the links go 404.

Comment: weird. link still works here

Answer (score -1):

I would just get a sound bar.

not as good as actual 2 back speakers, but better then 2, and can't beat its simplicity (one item replacing 4 speakers, a dvd player and the AV box).

Comment: Since this is a DIY site and not a home theater site, advice on component selection rather than help with the DIY-related implementation probably isn't appropriate.

Comment: I think you are exaggerating the self importance of the universe... lighten up.

plus, it is perfectly good answer to tell someone the best way to do something is not doing it.

Comment: I'm with csmba  Sometimes the best answer is "Don't bother, do this instead"